# How to redirect subdomain to different ip from ubuntu webserver?

Tags: networking, server, dns, webserver

I'm hosting a webserver for a website (ex. asd.com) on an ubuntu machine at some IP  (ex. 1.1.1.1).  I want to host a subdomain (ex. abc.asd.com) on a different machine with a different IP.  How would I go about redirecting requests to the other machine?  The webserver is currently running Hiawatha with a node.js backend

Comment: Add a CNAME record to your DNS.

Comment: It depends if both servers have public ips. If both have public, what @Jos said (CNAME) or a `A` dns record  pointing to the other ip will work. If the subdomain host doesn't have a public ip, but it's reachable from the main host through the internal network, a reverser-proxy (line `nginx`) on the main domain can be used.